# Spring: Two dispatcher servlets for building DB and run App

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Assume I have following web.xml:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DBbuildServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/DBbuildServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DBbuildServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/app-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I would like to build DataBase in `DBbuildServlet` and postpone `appServlet` loading until DB built.

Is it possible? What is correct way of building DB on application run using Spring?

Comment: Use something like flyway to create the schema, you don't need multiple servlets for that.

Comment: @M.Deinum, building database in my case is not only about scheme: liquidbase, dataloders, etc involved.

Comment: Just put everything in a single servlet as stated you don't need 2 servlets.

Comment: I need different Spring contexts

Comment: Why on earth would you need different contexts...

Comment: Because one is for BD biuld that in plans will incrementally update DB, control file versions etc. Other is application scope with all it beans.

Comment: Basically, I just need two stages of application run. First of it deploy to Tomcat screen placeholder and build DB (application is big 18 min is DB build), another stage will deploy application and run main Spring context (it takes 5 min)

Comment: Second context depends on DB state

Comment: You don't need 2 contexts for that... You can do that perfectly well with a single context.

Comment: Well, I understand. This second context is production, architects will not permit me to change it. Can I have two sequentially loaded contexts in app?